# JWT Unable to decode the header as Base64Url encoded string

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I have the following code:

```
public async Task<LoginResult> GenerateJwtTokenAsync(string email, string password)
{
    LoginResult loginResult = await _membershipProvider.Login(email, password);
    if (loginResult.Succeeded)
    {
        var symmetricKey = Convert.FromBase64String(Secret);

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(loginResult.Claims),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKey), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };

        var stoken = _tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var token = _tokenHandler.WriteToken(stoken);

        // Check token here to see if it works
        var jwtToken = _tokenHandler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;
        loginResult.JwtToken = token;
    }
    return loginResult;
}

public ClaimsPrincipal ValidateJwtToken(string tokenString)
{

    ClaimsPrincipal principal;

    try
    {
        var jwtToken = _tokenHandler.ReadToken(tokenString) as JwtSecurityToken;

        if (jwtToken == null)
        {
            principal = null;
        }
        else
        {
            var symmetricKey = Convert.FromBase64String(Secret);

            var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKey)
            };

            SecurityToken securityToken;
            principal = _tokenHandler.ValidateToken(tokenString, validationParameters, out securityToken);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        principal = null;
    }

    return principal;
}
```

The line below reads the token perfectly, however when I actually read it in the 2nd method I get an exception.

```
// Check token here to see if it works
var jwtToken = _tokenHandler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken
```

I have verified the two string are identical, I am extremely confused as to why this stops working when I actually want to validate the token for the life of me I can't see what I am doing wrong. Any ideas please?

EDIT:

Exception

```
   "IDX10729: Unable to decode the header 'header' as Base64Url encoded string. jwtEncodedString: 'Token here'."
```

Stack trace:

```
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken.Decode(String[] tokenParts, String rawData)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(String token)
   at AuthService.ValidateJwtToken(String tokenString) in AuthService.cs:line 57
```

Comment: "I get an exception" - and what is that exception? **Always** give the details of any errors you receive...

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry I typed quickly, partially put it in the header because it's a big exception, will update now :D

Comment: You've still only shown the InnerException, and apparently only bits of it. A full stack trace with *all* inner exceptions would be easier to understand. (Given that it's a *type initializer* that's failing, this appears to be using different code...)

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry been a really long day, really not with it lol - updated again.

Comment: `jwtEncodedString: 'Token here'` doesn't look like it's appropriate. Is that something you've changed yourself and it's really a valid token, or not? It really feels like you've probably got two different strings here, even if you *think* they're the same. I'd add more logging.

Comment: @JonSkeet I removed it for the purpose of the demonstration as it didn't feel write to have a big encrypted JWT token in the question. I had a thought on the drive home, the reading and creating of the token happens in my API & I then have a different authentication filter for MVC to ensure that the token is valid, potentially because they are operating on separate threads/app domains would explain why the generation can create/read the token but the MVC authentication filter can't...

Comment: Right. It definitely sounds like more logging is required.

Comment: @JonSkeet Not quite sure what more I can log, I can debug this locally so it's not environmental and the line that's throwing an exception is the JWT library itself and I have logged out the token(s) in both methods, they are identical. What else do you recommend I log because it's pretty isolated to me?

Comment: If they're genuinely, really identical, and you're using the exact same library in both places, I would start trying to rip as many other pieces out as possible... reduce it to a minimal example.

Answer (score 16):

I was having this error and found, by observing the error detail, that the cause was that `Newtonsoft.Json` dll was not loaded.

The `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JsonExtensions` was trying to load version 9.0.0.0 of the dll but the project was using version 10.0.0.0. The error detail have something like this:

> System.ArgumentException: IDX10729: ... Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies

I resolved by adding this binding to the config:

```
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding  xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: Take into account that in case the solution references this component in different projects, more than one config could be created for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Try updating the library to a most recent version. In my case, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=6.5.0.0 solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error validating the token. I solved adding the Newtonsoft.Json dll to the project.

Comment: Had same issue in the NUnit project, while main project worked well. Found that projects used different version of Newtonsoft.Json, after refresh version for NUnit problem disappear.

Answer (score 0):

The JWT library (e.g. ValidateToken') requires input token strings that have a length that is divisible by 4. You may need to 'right pad' the input to make it divisible by 4; the padding character is the equals sign.
For your second method, you can make sure that 'tokenString' is properly right padded with "=" by using this snippet:

```
 tokenString= tokenString.PadRight(tokenString.Length + (4 - tokenString.Length % 4) % 4, '=');
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when this package [System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt] **MISSING**, I got the slight similar exception like:

```
"IDX12729: Unable to decode the header '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]' as Base64Url encoded string. jwtEncodedString: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'."
```